# How do I remove the numbers from a datatable?

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a lightning datatable defined as follows:

```
<lightning-datatable data={data}
                     columns={columns}
                     key-field="Id"
                     enable-infinite-loading
                     onloadmore={handleLoadMore}
                     onheaderaction={handleHeaderAction}
                     onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                     onrowselection={handleRowSelection}>
```

Note the absence of `show-row-number-column`. According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification), "If present, the row numbers are shown in the first column," implying that if absent the numbers will be hidden. I see that this is what happens in the examples on that page. Their first example does not include that attribute and has no numbering, and if I add the `show-row-number-column` attribute, the numbers do show up.

I've tried using `show-row-number-column="false"` without success. How can I specifically say I *don't* want the numbers to show up?

Comment: Have you checked your columns and data objects to see if _they_ are defining the row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of the `lightning-datatable`.

When you set a column to `editable` then row numbers are added and you can't remove them.

Ref:

> By making a column editable, the show-row-number-column attribute is always true and the number column is displayed.

Source [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)